# How do I make linebreaks for innerhtml content in a p tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I'm making a simple application in javascript that allows you to write in a weekday and then get the school classes that you have for that day. It works fine and outputs the text in the p tag when I enter the day. That's not my problem.

I'd like to know how I make the output (the classes) go in a list format sort of. Like it doesnt go next to eachother on one line. Instead it goes line by line with linebreaks basically. How do I make that happen?

```html
<body>

  <p>Skriv in en dag</p>

  <input id="dag" />

  <button id="print">Klick</button>

  <p id="lektioner"></p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("print").onclick = function() {

      var måndagLektioner = "Engelska " + "Bild " + "Språk " + "Slöjd " + "Svenska";
      var tisdagLektioner = "So " + "Språk " + "No" + " Matte" + " Musik " + "Svenska";
      var onsdagLektioner = "Matte " + "So" + " Idrott" + " Engelska" + " No" + " Elevens val";
      var torsdagLektioner = "No " + "Hemkunskap " + "So " + "Samling " + "No " + "Språk"
      var fredagLektioner = "Svenska " + "Matte " + "Idrott " + "So";

      if (document.getElementById("dag").value == "måndag") {
        document.getElementById("lektioner").innerHTML = måndagLektioner;
      }
      if (document.getElementById("dag").value == "tisdag") {
        document.getElementById("lektioner").innerHTML = tisdagLektioner;
      }
      if (document.getElementById("dag").value == "onsdag") {
        document.getElementById("lektioner").innerHTML = onsdagLektioner;
      }
      if (document.getElementById("dag").value == "torsdag") {
        document.getElementById("lektioner").innerHTML = torsdagLektioner;
      }
      if (document.getElementById("dag").value == "fredag") {
        document.getElementById("lektioner").innerHTML = fredagLektioner;
      }

    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: You know the [<br>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) tag? Though looks like you would need a table or list instead of paragraphs.

Comment: If it's a list, don't use a `<p>` tag, use the `<ul>` (if unordered) or `<ol>` (if ordered) with `<li>` as your list items.

Comment: @SecondRikudo how do I use innerhtml in combination with <ol>?

Comment: Exactly as you would think. Although, you shouldn't really be using `.innerHTML` to begin with. Have a look at `document.createElement` and `node.appendChild`.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Okay, I'm goiing to take a look at that. I'm kind of new to javascript and in the process of learning it so I've only got the bare basics down.

Comment: I'm writing an answer to hopefully explain what I mean a bit better.

Comment: Just insert "<br />" where you want the break, e.g. `"So " + "Språk " + "<br />" + "No" + " Matte" + " Musik " + "Svenska";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Use  `.split(' ').join('<br />');` after variables to replace  (space) with `<br />` (new line). This way you will have every word on a new line.

```js
document.getElementById("print").onclick = function() {
    var måndagLektioner = "Engelska " + "Bild " + "Språk " + "Slöjd " + "Svenska";
    if (document.getElementById("dag").value=="måndag") {
        document.getElementById("lektioner").innerHTML = måndagLektioner.split(' ').join('<br />');
    }
}
```

```html
 <p>Skriv in en dag</p>
<input id="dag" />
<button id="print">Klick</button>
<p id="lektioner"></p>
```

---

**Solution 2:** Also, you can add a special character to make a difference between multiple words on same line, let's say we use `|` to separate them. You will do `.split('|').join('<br />');` like below.

```js
document.getElementById("print").onclick = function() {
    var måndagLektioner = "Engelska|" + "Bild " + "Språk|" + "Slöjd|" + "Svenska";
    if (document.getElementById("dag").value=="måndag") {
        document.getElementById("lektioner").innerHTML = måndagLektioner.split('|').join('<br />');
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Skriv in en dag</p>
<input id="dag" />
<button id="print">Klick</button>
<p id="lektioner"></p>
```

---

**Solution 3**: If you want to use other tags then `<br />` you can do some functions that will surround your words by a tag. The example below is for an unordered list `ul` and with `li` childs.

```js
function insertTag(word, tag) {
  var result = '<' + tag + '>' + word + '</' + tag + '>';
  return result;
}

function insertListTag(list, tag, innerTag) {
  var result = '<'+tag+'>';
  for(var word in list)
  {
     result += insertTag(list[word], innerTag);
  }
  result += '</'+tag+'>';
  return result;
}

document.getElementById("print").onclick = function() {
  var måndagLektioner = "Engelska|" + "Bild " + "Språk|" + "Slöjd|" + "Svenska";

  if (document.getElementById("dag").value=="måndag") {
    
    document.getElementById("lektioner").innerHTML = insertListTag(måndagLektioner.split('|'), 'ul', 'li');
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Skriv in en dag</p>
<input id="dag" />
<button id="print">Klick</button>
<p id="lektioner"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer probably works well, I'm going to present a more correct way of doing what you mean.

You have a list of classes, a list is represented in JavaScript in the form of an array.

```
var måndagLektioner = ["Engelska", "Bild", "Språk", "Slöjd", "Svenska"];
```

Then you can do things on that array (loop over it, join it into a string, etc).

You want a list representation on your document as well, for that we have 3 elements. The `<ul>` (unordered list) and `<ol>` (ordered list) as the parent, and `<li>` for each list item.

So let's loop over the array, create an `<li>` element for each item, and add that to the list

```
// Save all of your elements in variables, don't call getElementById
// more than once for the same element.
var print = document.getElementById("print");
var dag = document.getElementById("dag");
var lektioner = document.getElementById("lektioner");

// Use addEventListener, not onclick.
// This way you can have multiple event handlers on the same element.
print.addEventListener('click', function () {

    // Let's create an object. We can access a specific lesson array with
    // lessons["tisdagLektioner"] (for example)
    var lessons = {
        "måndagLektioner": ["Engelska", "Bild", "Språk", "Slöjd", "Svenska"],
        "tisdagLektioner": ["So", "Språk", "No" + " Matte" + " Musik", "Svenska"],
        "onsdagLektioner": ["Matte", "So", "Idrott", "Engelska", "No", "Elevens val"],
        "torsdagLektioner": ["No", "Hemkunskap", "So", "Samling", "No", "Språk"],
        "fredagLektioner": ["Svenska", "Matte", "Idrott", "So"]
    }

    // There are better ways to clear an element. But let's stick with the basics.
    lektioner.innerHTML = '';

    // if you wrote an entry in dag that's in our object
    if (lessons[dag.value]) {
        // Iterate that array.
        lessons[dag.value].forEach(function(lesson) {
            // Inside this function, item in the array is called "lesson".

            // Create an LI
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            // Make the text equal to the current lesson
            li.textContent = lesson;
            // Append to the UL.
            lektioner.appendChild(li);
        });
    }

});
```

You can have a look **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/zma0ev2d/)**

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest amending your JavaScript somewhat, to the following approach:

```
document.getElementById("print").onclick = function() {

  // create an object containing all the days' lessons:
  var dagar = {
    måndagLektioner: "Engelska " + "Bild " + "Språk " + "Slöjd " + "Svenska",
    tisdagLektioner: "So " + "Språk " + "No" + " Matte" + " Musik " + "Svenska",
    onsdagLektioner: "Matte " + "So" + " Idrott" + " Engelska" + " No" + " Elevens val",
    torsdagLektioner: "No " + "Hemkunskap " + "So " + "Samling " + "No " + "Språk",
    fredagLektioner: "Svenska " + "Matte " + "Idrott " + "So"
  },
      // get the value once, not repeatedly, using trim()
      // to remove leading, and trailing white-space,
      // convert to lower case to account for capitalisation
      // differences:
      value = document.getElementById('dag').value.trim().toLowerCase();

  // set the elements innerHTML to the value returned from the
  // created object, replacing the found white-space sequences
  // with <br />:
  document.getElementById('lektioner').innerHTML = dagar[ value + 'Lektioner'].replace(/\s+/g,'<br />');

}
```

```js
document.getElementById("print").onclick = function() {

  var dagar = {
    måndagLektioner: "Engelska " + "Bild " + "Språk " + "Slöjd " + "Svenska",
    tisdagLektioner: "So " + "Språk " + "No" + " Matte" + " Musik " + "Svenska",
    onsdagLektioner: "Matte " + "So" + " Idrott" + " Engelska" + " No" + " Elevens val",
    torsdagLektioner: "No " + "Hemkunskap " + "So " + "Samling " + "No " + "Språk",
    fredagLektioner: "Svenska " + "Matte " + "Idrott " + "So"
  },
      value = document.getElementById('dag').value.trim().toLowerCase();
  
  document.getElementById('lektioner').innerHTML = dagar[ value + 'Lektioner'].replace(/\s+/g,'<br />');

}
```

```html
<p>Skriv in en dag</p>

<input id="dag" />

<button id="print">Klick</button>

<p id="lektioner"></p>
```

Further, though, I'd suggest using arrays within the object, which allows lesson-names to contain white-spaces (`"Elevens val"`, for instance):

```
document.getElementById("print").onclick = function() {

  var dagar = {
    måndagLektioner: ["Engelska", "Bild", "Språk", "Slöjd", "Svenska"],
    tisdagLektioner: ["So", "Språk", "No","Matte", "Musik", "Svenska"],
    onsdagLektioner: ["Matte", "So", "Idrott", "Engelska", "No", "Elevens val"],
    torsdagLektioner: ["No", "Hemkunskap" , "So" , "Samling", "No" , "Språk"],
    fredagLektioner: ["Svenska" , "Matte", "Idrott" , "So"]
  },
      value = document.getElementById('dag').value.trim().toLowerCase();

  document.getElementById('lektioner').innerHTML = dagar[ value + 'Lektioner'].join('<br />');

}
```

```js
document.getElementById("print").onclick = function() {

  var dagar = {
    måndagLektioner: ["Engelska", "Bild", "Språk", "Slöjd", "Svenska"],
    tisdagLektioner: ["So", "Språk", "No","Matte", "Musik", "Svenska"],
    onsdagLektioner: ["Matte", "So", "Idrott", "Engelska", "No", "Elevens val"],
    torsdagLektioner: ["No", "Hemkunskap" , "So" , "Samling", "No" , "Språk"],
    fredagLektioner: ["Svenska" , "Matte", "Idrott" , "So"]
  },
      value = document.getElementById('dag').value.trim().toLowerCase();
  
  document.getElementById('lektioner').innerHTML = dagar[ value + 'Lektioner'].join('<br />');

}
```

```html
<p>Skriv in en dag</p>

<input id="dag" />

<button id="print">Klick</button>

<p id="lektioner"></p>
```

And, frankly, since you're clearly working with an ordered list, I'd be remiss if I didn't suggest (and quite strongly) that you use an `<ol>` rather than a `<p>`:

```
document.getElementById("print").onclick = function() {

  var dagar = {
      måndagLektioner: ["Engelska", "Bild", "Språk", "Slöjd", "Svenska"],
      tisdagLektioner: ["So", "Språk", "No", "Matte", "Musik", "Svenska"],
      onsdagLektioner: ["Matte", "So", "Idrott", "Engelska", "No", "Elevens val"],
      torsdagLektioner: ["No", "Hemkunskap", "So", "Samling", "No", "Språk"],
      fredagLektioner: ["Svenska", "Matte", "Idrott", "So"]
    },
    value = document.getElementById('dag').value.trim().toLowerCase(),
    // create a document fragment, to contain the HTML (rather
    // than forcing a redraw every time a new element is added):
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    // creating an <li> element:
    li = document.createElement('li'),
    // a named, but uninitialised, variable to use within the loop:
    clone;

  // using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the lessons array:
  dagar[value + 'Lektioner'].forEach(function(lesson) {
    // cloning the created <li> (to avoid calling
    // document.createElement() multiple times):
    clone = li.cloneNode();

    // setting the text to the string held in the current
    // array-element over which we're iterating:
    clone.textContent = lesson;

    // appending the cloned <li> to the document fragment:
    frag.appendChild(clone);
  });

  // appending the document fragment to the element with the
  // id of 'lektioner':
  document.getElementById('lektioner').appendChild(frag);

}
```

```js
document.getElementById("print").onclick = function() {

  var dagar = {
      måndagLektioner: ["Engelska", "Bild", "Språk", "Slöjd", "Svenska"],
      tisdagLektioner: ["So", "Språk", "No", "Matte", "Musik", "Svenska"],
      onsdagLektioner: ["Matte", "So", "Idrott", "Engelska", "No", "Elevens val"],
      torsdagLektioner: ["No", "Hemkunskap", "So", "Samling", "No", "Språk"],
      fredagLektioner: ["Svenska", "Matte", "Idrott", "So"]
    },
    value = document.getElementById('dag').value.trim().toLowerCase(),
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    li = document.createElement('li'),
    clone;

  dagar[value + 'Lektioner'].forEach(function(lesson) {
    clone = li.cloneNode();
    clone.textContent = lesson;
    frag.appendChild(clone);
  });

  document.getElementById('lektioner').appendChild(frag);

}
```

```html
<p>Skriv in en dag</p>

<input id="dag" />

<button id="print">Klick</button>

<ol id="lektioner"></ol>
```

Also, rather than using `element.onclick` I'd suggest using `HTMLElement.addEventListener()` to be more standards-compliant:

```
function showDay() {

  var dagar = {
      måndagLektioner: ["Engelska", "Bild", "Språk", "Slöjd", "Svenska"],
      tisdagLektioner: ["So", "Språk", "No", "Matte", "Musik", "Svenska"],
      onsdagLektioner: ["Matte", "So", "Idrott", "Engelska", "No", "Elevens val"],
      torsdagLektioner: ["No", "Hemkunskap", "So", "Samling", "No", "Språk"],
      fredagLektioner: ["Svenska", "Matte", "Idrott", "So"]
    },
    value = document.getElementById('dag').value.trim().toLowerCase(),
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    li = document.createElement('li'),
    clone;

  dagar[value + 'Lektioner'].forEach(function(lesson) {
    clone = li.cloneNode();
    clone.textContent = lesson;
    frag.appendChild(clone);
  });

  document.getElementById('lektioner').appendChild(frag);

}

// getting references to the <button> and the <input />:
var button = document.getElementById('print'),
    dayInput = document.getElementById('dag');

// adding the showDay() function as the event-handler for:
// the 'click' event on the <button>:
button.addEventListener('click', showDay);
// the 'change' event on the <input />:
dag.addEventListener('change', showDay);
```

```js
function showDay() {

  var dagar = {
      måndagLektioner: ["Engelska", "Bild", "Språk", "Slöjd", "Svenska"],
      tisdagLektioner: ["So", "Språk", "No", "Matte", "Musik", "Svenska"],
      onsdagLektioner: ["Matte", "So", "Idrott", "Engelska", "No", "Elevens val"],
      torsdagLektioner: ["No", "Hemkunskap", "So", "Samling", "No", "Språk"],
      fredagLektioner: ["Svenska", "Matte", "Idrott", "So"]
    },
    value = document.getElementById('dag').value.trim().toLowerCase(),
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    li = document.createElement('li'),
    clone;

  dagar[value + 'Lektioner'].forEach(function(lesson) {
    clone = li.cloneNode();
    clone.textContent = lesson;
    frag.appendChild(clone);
  });

  document.getElementById('lektioner').appendChild(frag);

}

var button = document.getElementById('print'),
    dayInput = document.getElementById('dag');

button.addEventListener('click', showDay);
dag.addEventListener('change', showDay);
```

```html
<p>Skriv in en dag</p>

<input id="dag" />

<button id="print">Klick</button>

<ol id="lektioner"></ol>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).